# How to define ID type in Nestjs + Graphql Mutation Args?

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs

I am searching one things. Actually I am building a `graphql api` with `nestjs`. Here I want to ID type in `@Args` Input.

Here is example-

```
import { Resolver, Mutation, Query, Args, Context, ID } from "@nestjs/graphql";

@Mutation(() => SuccessInfo, { name: "addSubCategory" })
addSub(
        @Args("id") id: ID  // Here is type ID
    ) {
    console.log(id);
}
```

Here I import `ID` type from `@nestjs/graphql`. And add type as `id`. But I getting one error like-

`'ID' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof ID'?`

`Parameter 'id' of public method from exported class has or is using private name 'ID'`

Then I try to add `typeof ID`.

```
import { Resolver, Mutation, Query, Args, Context, ID } from "@nestjs/graphql";

@Mutation(() => SuccessInfo, { name: "addSubCategory" })
addSub(
        @Args("id") id: typeof ID  // Here is type ID
    ) {
    console.log(id);
}
```

Then It solve `typescript` error. But I also get error in console when starting the server-

[image]

`Undefined type error. Make sure you are providing an explicit type for the "addSub"`

But When I give `String`. It works perfectly. But I need to add `ID`.

```
import { Resolver, Mutation, Query, Args, Context, ID } from "@nestjs/graphql";

@Mutation(() => SuccessInfo, { name: "addSubCategory" })
addSub(
        @Args("id") id: String  // Here is type ID
    ) {
    console.log(id);
}
```

Here I need ID type How can I define ID type from here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct way to do it:

```
import { Resolver, Mutation, Query, Args, Context, ID } from "@nestjs/graphql";

@Mutation(() => SuccessInfo, { name: "addSubCategory" })
addSub(
    @Args("id", { type: () => ID } ) id: string  // Notice it's string not String
) {
    console.log(id);
    return { status: true } // return anything here which matches the SuccessInfo type
}
```

Comment: Not working. Are you sure it is correct way?

Comment: You mistake something something. It will be-

`@Args("id", {type: () => ID}) id: ObjectId`